# Clean way to select from many options in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, conventions, rdkit

I work in data science and a typical problem I encounter while cleaning up Pandas dataframes is converting columns from one string format to another (in particular, the strings I'm looking at are chemical identifiers and each of them represents a molecule in a obscure way, so it's not like the strings are easily understandable just by looking at them). I have many small functions (inherited from a chemical library called RDKit) to convert between formats, and there is roughly one function per conversion pair (i.e. input format and output format). This is too many function names to remember. I want to write a wrapper function that aggregates all of them into a single, larger one with a clean design and user interface.

The question is: given an input and output format, what would be a clean way to select from a many possible small conversion functions? Should I use a dictionary that stores the small conversion function names?

For example, let's say I want to convert from the format "smiles" to the format "inchi keys",  which I currently do as follows:

```
from rdkit import Chem


def smile2inchikey(smile):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smile)
    inchikey = Chem.inchi.MolToInchiKey(mol)
    return inchikey
```

Instead of manually calling `smile2inchikey`  (or `Chem.MolFromSmiles` and `Chem.inchi.MolToInchiKey`), I would like to write the following function:

```
def fancy_multiconverter(input_string, input_format, output_format):
    pass
```

which returns `input_string` (given in the format `input_format`) to the format `output_format`).

Comment: How does the user give input and output format? Does (s)he submit a name which is asociated with a certain format?

Comment: Maybe you should make a conversation class? From reading your post that is what springs to mind.

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone for the quick replies. @Carcigenicate I have tried to make the question more specific and I've added an example. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: @JakobSchödl I should have made it clearer that I am going to be the main user of this function/script, as it is something I will use daily in my data cleaning.

Comment: @QuintenCabo I have no preference for a function or a class. How would a conversion class work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is also what @Quinten Cabo meant, but you could use one unit that you convert to every time.

You could then use a dictionary with functions for converting into and from this unit:

```
convert_to_reference = {
                         "format1": function1,
                         "format2": function2,
                       }
convert_from_reference = {
                           ...
                         }
reference = convert_to_reference[input("input format: ")](input("input value: "))
output = convert_from_reference[input("output format: ")](reference)
print(output)
```

Comment: I also thought this may be the best possible way. Thanks a lot!